# MUITA demora no requests.get Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Estou tendo um problema que quando eu realizo o `requests.get` **diversas** vezes, o python começa a demorar MUITO tempo para conseguir o `request`.

Já pensei que pode ser a própria API recusando  o meu acesso, pois estaria realizando mais que o permitido, mas de acordo com [este link](https://api.brasilbitcoin.com.br/?version=latest#introducao) pude afirmar que este não era o problema. *(Mas como realmente não faço ideia do que está acontecendo, entrei em contato e me afirmaram que é realmente este o limite de requisições, que o site está correto.)*

E este problema já me aconteceu anteriormente com outro link, então não sei o que o porquê está acontecendo este problema.

O que o meu sistema faz, seria algo **similar** a:

```
import requests
import time

While True:
  
 requests.get("https://brasilbitcoin.com.br/API/orderbook/XRP")

 '''
  trato o requests.get
 '''

 time.sleep(1)
```

Já confirmei que o problema é o `requests` e não de qualquer outra parte do código.
Anteriormente não havia o `time.sleep(1)` mas acabei adicionando-o por via das dúvidas.

Quando digo que realizo muitas requisições, estou falando 1 por segundo durante 24h por dia.
Mas a partir de um tempo a requisição começou a ficar EXTREMAMENTE lenta. Quando eu reinicio o servidor para ver se é este o problema, ele volta a fazer as requisições muito bem, mas quando chega por volta de 200 requisições começa a demorar demais novamente.

(Nesse exato momento está demorando ~44 segundos POR requisição neste link, e a tendência está sendo este tempo aumentar cada vez mais).

Alguém sabe me dizer o que pode estar acontecendo?

**Estou usando Windows e Python 3.8.2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já testou enviar explicitamente um `keep_alive=False`? Experimenta modificar a configuração logo antes da tua iteração. Implementando dessa forma consegui observar 500+ requisições no stdout.

```
import requests
import time

i = 0
s = requests.Session()
s.stream = False

while True:
    req = s.get("https://brasilbitcoin.com.br/API/orderbook/XRP")
    print("req:", i)
    i += 1

    # trata o req

    time.sleep(1)
```

Acredito que ou podes estar atingindo o limite de `requests` abertas pelo teu processo python, ou o limite de requisições imposta pela API. Eu não descartaria a segunda opção mesmo que estejas seguindo a documentação, respeitando o intervalo de 1 req/seg.

Já tive problemas com APIs de outras exchanges, e a solução que tomei foi migrar para websocket, mas infelizmente acredito que no teu caso não seja uma opção já que eles não oferecem uma API wss :(

Versão da requests que utilizei (saída de `pip3 show requests`):

```
Name: requests
Version: 2.24.0
Summary: Python HTTP for Humans.
Home-page: https://requests.readthedocs.io
Author: Kenneth Reitz
Author-email: me@kennethreitz.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/lzgustavo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: certifi, urllib3, chardet, idna
```

Comment: Nessa versão do script faltou verificar o status code da resposta, mas testei denovo printando dentro da condição `if req.status_code == 200:` e chegou a mais ou menos esse número também antes de eu finalizar o processo. Acho que funcionou!

Comment: Muito obrigado !
Uma dúvida que eu tenho, onde posso ler mais sobre wss em python ? Estava querendo utilizar a FoxBit e a Coinext mas elas usam websocket e não consigo entender como funciona =\

Comment: wss especificamente em Python eu não sei te ajudar :( 
Implementei em Go utilizando [gorilla websocket](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket), consultando direto pela documentação das APIs (binance, coinbase) e pela [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455). Se decidir seguir com Go e precisar de ajuda só chamar.

Answer (score 2):

Não há nada de errado com o `Python` e nem com a biblioteca `requests`!

Suas requisições repetidas com esse curto intervalo de tempo entre elas, certamente está fazendo com que o servidor "alvo" entenda que se trata de um "ataque".

O tempo de resposta está cada vez mais alto pois o servidor está penalizando seu endereço de origem devido ao grande volume de requisições em um curto espaço de tempo.

A [documentação](https://api.brasilbitcoin.com.br/?version=latest#limites-de-requisicoes) da API REST que você está acessando diz o seguinte:

> **Autenticação e Respostas**
>
> A chave de autenticação deve ser enviada no cabeçalho da requisição, e
> as respostas serão devolvidas em JSON.
>
> **Limites de Requisições**
>
> O limite de requisições é de 4 requisições por minuto para criação de
> ordens. Para as outras chamadas, o limite é de 1 requisição por
> segundo. O parâmtro 'wait', quando houver refere-se ao tempo em
> segundos restante para a realização de uma nova chamada.

Existe mesmo a necessidade de se fazer esse volume de requisições em um espaço tão curto de tempo?

Comment: Realmente precisa ser feito neste curto intervalo de tempo, inclusive, precisa tanto ser feito que o próprio servidor deles autorizam apenas 1 requisição por segundo (que é o que eu faço)... Porque 4 segundos já é extremamente muito tempo para uma análise intensiva do mercado :(

Comment: Logo, respondendo outra parte da sua "pergunta", acredito que não seja o problema do servidor estar me penalizando, por conta do que é documentado na api ..

Comment: @user3602803: A documentação da API também fala sobre uma "chave de autenticação". O problema acontece quando essa chave é enviada no cabeçalho da requisição ?

Comment: Todas as APIS deles são juntas neste site, essa referência sobre a "Chave de authenticação" é para operações que dependem da minha conta de usuário e da minha API_KEY, por exemplo, verificar saldos, realizar operações, entre outros, se for reparar, você consegue acessar o REST deles pelo seu próprio navegador sem nenhum cabeçalho

Comment: @user3602803 se não é a API (vale checar o parâmetro `wait` que eles citam na documentação), pode ser algo que você faz na parte que não mostrou do código, e que esteja sobrecarregando o seu servidor. Por exemplo, criação de threads.

Comment: Boa! Vou dar uma checada e lhe informo em seguida

Comment: @Lacobus Sem sucesso.. Continua lento